# make validations in powermail work without declaring the field as required (TYPO3 10, Powermail)

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

is there a possibiliy to make the validations work without declaring the whole field as requiered?

For instance i need a restriction to a given number of characters for all input fields. Well, not all input fields are requiered, but none must contain more than the given number of characters.

It works fine in all fields which are required but not on non required fields. On these fields every validator is ignored. Is there a possiblity to change this behavior? I would need such validations in every second form ... (e.g. restrict to numbers, restrict to correct email without forcing the input of an email address and so on).

Thanks!

Comment: I stumbled over that problem recently. If a field is required, the JavaScript validation takes place right after you leave the input field. Otherwise the JavaScript validation is only executed when you submit the form. Does this help you?

Comment: Hi, thanks für your answer. It does not work for me - when i submit the form the javaScript validation is not executed in fields without the validation required.